# Include Binary relationship condition in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a binary relationship between 2 tables and I need to translate that in to Entity framework
it is in this way *TypesDescUse* field in *Indexs* table contain some numbers. you need to see them as binary value and the id of them are in *DescUse* in traditional TSQL by binary relation can have the name from DescUse table.

> example1: 0001 & 0011 is 0001 and 1 in DescUse has name by value
> "web site"
>
> example2:  1010 & 1000 is 1000 and 8 in DescUse has name by value "Desktop"

```
select  DU.Name AS Name from Indexs I 
INNER JOIN DescUse DU ON I.TypesDescUse & DU.DescUseID <>0
```

do you have any idea how can i do that in lambda Entity framework ?

Comment: thanks julia what about lambda version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from I in Indexs
join DU in DescUse on true equals true 
where (I.TypesDescUse & DU.DescUseID) != 0
select new {Name = I.Name};
```

OR

```
 Indexs.Join(DescUse,
             I => true,
             DU => true,
             (I, DU) => new { IVal = I.TypesDescUse, DUVal = DU.DescUseID, Name = DU.Name })
       .Where(x => (x.IVal & x.DUVal) != 0).Select(x => x.Name)
```